# Cannot Telnet to a device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, telnet

I have this Biometric Device and I can ping the device but I can’t telnet to the port that the device does.

[image]

Here’s I can’t telnet my device. I already turned off the firewall and AntiVirus app with firewall. Still, I can't telnet to the device. How do I fix this thing?

[image]

Example of a device I can telnet to:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that port 4370 is the correct telnet port?

Comment: @JakeGould Yes. I have several devices and all ports are 4370

Comment: Is telnet allowed on the device? Give Putty a try too.